# Convert file references in Xcode to files

Tags: xcode

I am new to XCode and I want to convert file references from another project into files in my project folder. I should've done the copying to folder at the time I did a drag and drop but unfortunately I didn't notice at that time.

I tried removing the references and manually copying the said files into my project folder but that is causing build errors I can't understand. Xcode is unable to recognize the classes in the newly copied files.

When I remove the references to the files I see the following diff being generated in the project.pbxproj file

```
-               9EA3AE481AFBE3DC006D1736 /* PasscodeLock.swift in Sources */ = {isa = PBXBuildFile; fileRef = 9EA3AE3F1AFBE3DC006D1736 /* PasscodeLock.swift */; };
-               9EA3AE491AFBE3DC006D1736 /* PasscodeLockPresenter.swift in Sources */ = {isa = PBXBuildFile; fileRef = 9EA3AE401AFBE3DC006D1736 /* PasscodeLockPresenter.swift */; };
-               9EA3AE4A1AFBE3DC006D1736 /* ChangePasscodeState.swift in Sources */ = {isa = PBXBuildFile; fileRef = 9EA3AE421AFBE3DC006D1736 /* ChangePasscodeState.swift */; };
-               9EA3AE4B1AFBE3DC006D1736 /* ConfirmPasscodeState.swift in Sources */ = {isa = PBXBuildFile; fileRef = 9EA3AE431AFBE3DC006D1736 /* ConfirmPasscodeState.swift */; };
-               9EA3AE4C1AFBE3DC006D1736 /* EnterPasscodeState.swift in Sources */ = {isa = PBXBuildFile; fileRef = 9EA3AE441AFBE3DC006D1736 /* EnterPasscodeState.swift */; };
-               9EA3AE4D1AFBE3DC006D1736 /* PasscodesMismatchState.swift in Sources */ = {isa = PBXBuildFile; fileRef = 9EA3AE451AFBE3DC006D1736 /* PasscodesMismatchState.swift */; };
-               9EA3AE4E1AFBE3DC006D1736 /* SetPasscodeState.swift in Sources */ = {isa = PBXBuildFile; fileRef = 9EA3AE461AFBE3DC006D1736 /* SetPasscodeState.swift */; };
```

Is there an easy way to convert all these references into files in my project folder?

Answer (score 0):

I was able to individually copy the files and build. The mistake I was making was that I was adding a files to an extra target.